# Universal app running at correct resolution on iPad 2 but in iphone/scaled mode retina iPads

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode7

I'm testing an iPhone app which is intended to also run on iPad. When I test it on an iPad 2, it scales up and runs fine as a full screen app. However when it's run on any retina iPad, it runs in scaled mode and the user can choose between 1x and 2x magnification.

As far as I can tell I've set all the settings to be universal. So why is it still running in 'iPhone mode' on the retina iPad?

[image]
[image]
Launch settings:
[image]

Comment: What are the launch screen settings?

Comment: It's dependent on the Launch Images available. I recommend you use Asset Catalog for Launch Images and it will be automatically fixed.

Comment: I've added another screenshot. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the relevance of these settings, is there some more detail somewhere about them?

Comment: @Kuldeep1007tanwar which constants should I set? I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: It depends on the number of objects and view u have in your ViewController .

Comment: Your life will be much easier if you use a single launch screen file instead of a whole bunch of launch images. Then your app will be able to support the iPad Pro too.